# Xunit Reporting Tool

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, report, xunit, xunit.net

Are there any open-source tools out there that can take in my xunit results file, and display it in a GUI? I looked into ReportUnit but it currently does not support xunit. Test cases are broken up into categories so I would be able to see a nice view of the test cases split by category. Any idea of any tools out there?

Answer (score -1):

Old thread but thought I'd post anyway in case someone else lands here...

[ReportPortal](https://reportportal.io/)
[Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/)

Comment: Why the downvote? I can confirm from experience that ReportPortal provides the requested functionality. While I haven't used Allure myself the documentation clearly indicates that it also provides the requested functionality.